# Find total of a value from List<Obj> using Java8 streams

Tags: java, collections, java-8, stream, java-stream

Below is my json request. My requirement is to find total of the **"cols"."value"** field if **"cols"."name"="tran_amt"**.

```
{
  "request" : {
    "reqID" : "6839796504132",
    "processID" : 97904250,
    "tables" : [ {
      "tableName" : "TABLE_NAME",
      "records" : [ {
        "recordID" : "record_id1",
        "cols" : [ {
          "name" : "tran_amt",
          "type" : "VARCHAR2",
          "value" : "562356"
        }, {
          "name" : "tran_id",
          "type" : "VARCHAR2",
          "value" : "123456"
        } ]
      }, {
        "recordID" : "record_id2",
        "cols" : [ {
          "name" : "tran_amt",
          "type" : "VARCHAR2",
          "value" : "987098"
        }, {
          "name" : "tran_id",
          "type" : "VARCHAR2",
          "value" : "123456"
        } ]
      } ]
    } ]
  }
}
```

Here is the solution I had tried,

```
cols = request.getTables().get(0).getRecords().get(0).getCols();
total = cols.stream().filter(o -> "tran_amt".equalsIgnoreCase(o.getName())).mapToInt(o -> Integer.valueOf(o.getValue())).sum();
```

My solution retrieves the "value" from the first obj of "cols" only (in this case 562356). It doesnt sum all "values" matching the criteria.

Any inputs on where I am wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `...getRecords().get(0)...` would seem to fetch only the first record in the collection.  You need to iterate over all records.  Conceptually, stream over `...getRecords()` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
total = request.getTables()
               .stream()
               .flatMap(t -> t.getRecords().stream())
               .flatMap(r -> r.getCols().stream())
               .filter(c -> "tran_amt".equalsIgnoreCase(c.getName()))
               .mapToInt(c -> Integer.valueOf(c.getValue()))
               .sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sum up all values of `value` field in `Col` from all `Records` for first table at `0` index

```
total = getTables().get(0)
             .getRecords()
             .stream()
             .map(Col::getCols)
             .flatMap(List::stream)
             .filter(o -> "tran_amt".equalsIgnoreCase(o.getName()))
             .mapToInt(o -> Integer.valueOf(o.getValue())).sum();
```